# To install ia32-libs on debian wheezy amd64

Tags: linux, debian, x86-64

I'm using Debian 7 (wheezy) amd64.

```
uname -a
Linux tzwm-debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And I want to install `ia32-libs` in my Debian. But this happens when I try to install.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And I google for it, then try to do it.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

The problem is not being solved.
Then I try to install `ia32-libs-i386`.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-i386:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs-i386:i386 : Depends: freeglut3:i386 (>= 2.6.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: lesstif2:i386 (>= 1:0.95.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libacl1:i386 (>= 2.2.49-4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libasyncns0:i386 (>= 0.3-1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libattr1:i386 (>= 1:2.4.44-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libaudio2:i386 (>= 1.9.2-4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libaudiofile1:i386 (>= 0.2.6-8) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libavahi-client3:i386 (>= 0.6.27-2+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libavahi-common3:i386 (>= 0.6.27-2+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libbsd0:i386 (>= 0.2.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcap2:i386 (>= 1:2.19-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcomerr2:i386 (>= 1.41.12-4stable1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcups2:i386 (>= 1.4.4-7+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcurl3:i386 (>= 7.21.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.2.24-4+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdirectfb-1.2-9:i386 (>= 1.2.10.0-4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.21-1~squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.21-1~squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.21-1~squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libedit2:i386 (>= 2.11-20080614-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libesd0:i386 (>= 0.2.41-8) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libexif12:i386 (>= 0.6.19-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 2.0.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libflac8:i386 (>= 1.2.1-2+b1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libfltk1.1:i386 (>= 1.1.10-2+b1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.8.0-2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.4.2-2.1+squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgcrypt11:i386 (>= 1.4.5-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgdbm3:i386 (>= 1.8.3-9) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.7.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (>= 7.7.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 (>= 7.7.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgnutls26:i386 (>= 2.8.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgpg-error0:i386 (>= 1.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgphoto2-2:i386 (>= 2.4.6-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgphoto2-port0:i386 (>= 2.4.6-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (>= 1.8.3+dfsg-4squeeze2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libice6:i386 (>= 2:1.0.6-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libidn11:i386 (>= 1.15-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libieee1284-3:i386 (>= 0.2.11-6) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libjack-jackd2-0:i386 (>= 1.9.5~dfsg-14) but it is not going to be installed or
                                libjack0:i386 (>= 1:0.118+svn3796-7) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libjpeg62:i386 (>= 6b1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libjpeg8:i386 (>= 8b-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libk5crypto3:i386 (>= 1.8.3+dfsg-4squeeze2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libkeyutils1:i386 (>= 1.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libkrb5-3:i386 (>= 1.8.3+dfsg-4squeeze2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libkrb5support0:i386 (>= 1.8.3+dfsg-4squeeze2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: liblcms1:i386 (>= 1.18.dfsg-1.2+b3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libltdl7:i386 (>= 2.2.6b-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: liblzo2-2:i386 (>= 2.03-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libmpg123-0:i386 (>= 1.12.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libnspr4-0d:i386 (>= 4.8.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libnss3-1d:i386 (>= 3.12.8-1+squeeze4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libogg0:i386 (>= 1.2.0~dfsg-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libopenal1:i386 (>= 1:1.12.854-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libpam0g:i386 (>= 1.1.1-6.1+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libpng12-0:i386 (>= 1.2.44-1+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libpopt0:i386 (>= 1.16-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.9.21-3+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsamplerate0:i386 (>= 0.1.7-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsane:i386 (>= 1.0.21-9) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsasl2-2:i386 (>= 2.1.23.dfsg1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsdl1.2debian:i386 (>= 1.2.15) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libselinux1:i386 (>= 2.0.96-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386 (>= 2.2.4.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsm6:i386 (>= 2:1.1.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsndfile1:i386 (>= 1.0.21-3+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsqlite3-0:i386 (>= 3.7.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libssh2-1:i386 (>= 1.2.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 (>= 1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libstdc++5:i386 (>= 1:3.3.6-20) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsvga1:i386 (>= 1:1.4.3-29) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsysfs2:i386 (>= 2.1.0+repack-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libtasn1-3:i386 (>= 2.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libtdb1:i386 (>= 1.2.1-2+b1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libtiff4:i386 (>= 3.9.4-5+squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libts-0.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0-7) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libusb-0.1-4:i386 (>= 2:0.1.12-16) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libuuid1:i386 (>= 2.17.2-9) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libvorbis0a:i386 (>= 1.3.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libvorbisenc2:i386 (>= 1.3.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libvorbisfile3:i386 (>= 1.3.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libwrap0:i386 (>= 7.6.q-19) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libx11-6:i386 (>= 2:1.3.3-4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libx86-1:i386 (>= 1.1+ds1-6) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxau6:i386 (>= 1:1.0.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxaw7:i386 (>= 2:1.0.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcb-render-util0:i386 (>= 0.3.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcb-render0:i386 (>= 1.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcb1:i386 (>= 1.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcomposite1:i386 (>= 1:0.4.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcursor1:i386 (>= 1:1.1.10-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxdamage1:i386 (>= 1:1.1.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxdmcp6:i386 (>= 1:1.0.3-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxext6:i386 (>= 2:1.1.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxfixes3:i386 (>= 1:4.0.5-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxft2:i386 (>= 2.1.14-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxi6:i386 (>= 2:1.3-6) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxinerama1:i386 (>= 2:1.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.7.8.dfsg-2+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxmu6:i386 (>= 2:1.0.5-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxmuu1:i386 (>= 2:1.0.5-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxp6:i386 (>= 1:1.0.0.xsf1-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxpm4:i386 (>= 1:3.5.8-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxrandr2:i386 (>= 2:1.3.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxrender1:i386 (>= 1:0.9.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxslt1.1:i386 (>= 1.1.26-6) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxss1:i386 (>= 1:1.2.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxt6:i386 (>= 1:1.0.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxtst6:i386 (>= 2:1.1.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxv1:i386 (>= 2:1.0.5-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxxf86vm1:i386 (>= 1:1.1.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: odbcinst1debian2:i386 (>= 2.2.14p2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libodbc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: xaw3dg:i386 (>= 1.5+E-18) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also try to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.13-38) but 2.17-93 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Should I must install libc6(=2.17-93) manually?

Is there a solution?

Comment: Looks like you mixed your repository list. I suspect that because that version of freeglut only exists in Debian 6 (squeeze), not 7 (wheezy).

Comment: My repository list is using http://mirrors.163.com/.help/sources.list.wheezy

Comment: In that case, can you run `apt-get update`, and then try again? It looks like your Packages index is old.

Comment: I have run `apt-get update` many times.

Comment: related: [How to install ia32-libs in Debian Wheezy?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83370) on unix/linux.SE also describes the `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` fix.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's probably late, but here is a way to fix this. Try this:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386 
apt-get update
apt-get install libc6:i386
```

Comment: For a possibly useful illustration of this solution, coupled with an illustration of how to solve the problem in jessie *without* `ia32-libs`, see [this debian-user post](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2014/05/msg00243.html) in (IMHO) a quite illuminating thread beginning [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2014/05/msg00126.html)

Comment: Lifesaver 3 lines. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

The `ia32-libs` maybe have been removed in the later version. And I have no way to solve this problem.

Finally, I find I should install `libc6-i386` instead of `ia32-libs`.

When I try to install `libc6-i386`, the following information is showed for me:

```
libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.13-38) but 2.17-93 is to be installed
```

I previously used the stable version. So I change to testing version, and install `libc6-i386` again successful.

Now I solved this problem and can run 32 bit application, although I don't know why I need a package in testing version to install package(libc6-i386) in stable version.

Comment: This worked for me: apt-get install libc6-i386, sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386, sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

Comment: This is exactly what I was encountering. Initially I was confused what you meant by stable and testing version but that was referring to the sources.list using by apt-get. Adding the testing version source back the the file resolved this exact issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use aptitude to install it:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo aptitude install ia32-libs
```

It will install all needed dependencies for ia32-libs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what fixed it for me. In my repositories, I had a CD-ROM source which was the original install disk, so when I'd run apt-get update, I'd get an error about apt-get not being able to add cd-rom repositories and that old indexes would be used (I don't have the exact error... my terminal just pushed it out of the buffer).

So I removed the cd-rom source from the repositories list (in synaptic), ran apt-get update again, and then I was able to install the ia32-libs.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility that has been suggested is to install libc6:i386.

Unfortunately installation of libc6:386 can result in the removal of core components and make your system unstable. You'lll get a message saying "You are about to do something potentially harmful. To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'"

Rather install libc6-i386.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an additional problem with the pinning preferences in /etc/apt/preferences .

When I put them just to support stable

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

apt finally found the way to do the proper dist-upgrade. I'm not sure why but when I installed my system (early 2012) the line specifying the pin release read:

```
Pin: release n=stable
```

so there was a "n" instead of an "a". Changing that worked like charm.