# Error while trying to open Acrobat Reader in Debian Bullseye

Tags: linux, debian, acrobat, bullseye

I installed Acrobat reader on Debian 11/Bullseye following instructions from [here](https://overbrace.com/bernardparent/viewtopic.php?t=1551)

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386
```

Download the Adobe Acrobat Reader (acroread) package here:
​ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb

​Install it as follows:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i  AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
acroread
```

When I run acroread from the terminal, I get the following error:

> opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread: error while loading shared libraries: libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I followed instructions in [this ubuntu forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2190132) and added i386 architecture (which is already done above):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

I understood that I need to install ia32-libs, which in debian is done [as per this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032019/to-install-ia32-libs-on-debian-wheezy-amd64)

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386  
apt-get update
apt-get install libc6:i386
```

Also followed advice to install libc6-i386 in the same thread.

But still get the error:

> /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread: error while loading shared libraries: libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please advice how to solve and any pointers will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 23):

I simply had to install the i386 package for libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386
```

Now acroread runs fine.

Comment: This additional step was also required on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and it resolved the issue described by the O.P.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah !
After quite a few trials and errors, this is how i could install acrobat reader on Ubuntu 22.04 :

```
$ wget ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb 
$ sudo dpkg -i AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb 
$ sudo apt-get install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386
```

At some point i also did

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

(but not sure that last line is required)